# How do I pass DTEXEC utility command line arguments to process.start using C# syntax?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ssis

I have to pass  parameters to DTEXEC utility through ASP.NET code. I am using the `process.start()` method to trigger the SSIS package execution.

#### String 1

```
dtexec /file C:\ssis\pkg1.dtsx 
       /conn "MyConnectionManager";"\"Data Source=localhost\TestSQL2008R2;Initial Catalog=ConnDB;Integrated Security=SSPI;\""
```

#### String 2

```
/file C:\ssis\pkg1.dtsx 
/conn "MyConnectionManager;Data Source=localhost\TestSQL2008R2;Initial Catalog=ConnDB;Integrated Security=SSPI;"
```

The above command line arguments are generated while manually executing the package through DTEXEC utility. However, I need to pass through this command line to `process.start()` method in ASP.NET using C#.

How can I represent the above command line within C# string statement? In other words, how do I escape the special characters by making use of **`@`** character and pass a valid statement to `process.start()`?

Comment: Where are the strings coming from? Do you mean they need to be hard coded?

Comment: assume they have to be hard coded

Comment: You sure you only have a single `"` in the second example?

Comment: sorry my bad the second one is dtexec /file C:\ssis\pkg1.dtsx /conn "MyConnectionManager;Data Source=localhost\TestSQL2008R2;Initial Catalog=ConnDB;Integrated Security=SSPI;"

Comment: Edit the post please - code is not suitable for comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A verbatim string literal is probably easiest to use for hard coding such strings.

You only need to double up every inner `"`:

```
@"dtexec /file C:\ssis\pkg1.dtsx /conn ""MyConnectionManager"";""\""Data Source=localhost\TestSQL2008R2;Initial Catalog=ConnDB;Integrated Security=SSPI;\""""";
```

And:

```
@"/file C:\ssis\pkg1.dtsx /conn ""MyConnectionManager;Data Source=localhost\TestSQL2008R2;Initial Catalog=ConnDB;Integrated Security=SSPI;""";
```

With "regular" strings, you would need to escape each `"` and `\` in the original with a `\` before them.

Answer (score 1):

At the risk of a downvote for being off topic, you have a better mechanism than calling the dtexec executable. Since you're in .net, use the existing [object model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.dts.runtime.aspx). It's *far* more powerful than the limited abstraction provided through dtexec.

Rough cut of the code would look like

```
string packagePath = @"C:\ssis\pkg1.dtsx";
string connectionString = @"Data Source=localhost\TestSQL2008R2;Initial Catalog=ConnDB;Integrated Security=SSPI;"
Application app = new Application();
Package pkg = null;
pkg = app.LoadPackage(packagePath, null);
pkg.Connections["MyConnectionManager"].ConnectionString = connectionString;
pkg.Execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't test these, but the following should do it.

```
var string1 = 
"dtexec /file C:\\ssis\\pkg1.dtsx /conn \"MyConnectionManager\";\"\\\"Data Source=localhost\\TestSQL2008R2;Initial Catalog=ConnDB;Integrated Security=SSPI;\\\"\"";

var string2 = "dtexec /file C:\\ssis\\pkg1.dtsx /conn \"MyConnectionManager;Data Source=localhost\\TestSQL2008R2;Initial Catalog=ConnDB;Integrated Security=SSPI;\"";
```

If you go the old fashioned route like I've shown above, you just need to escape `\` (because that IS your escape char) and `"` with a `\` anywhere in the string. If you use ver batim like the other answer suggests, it will be easier to read and maintain.