# Run SSIS package in asp.net using powershell

Tags: asp.net, powershell, ssis, package

Can anyone tell me how to run SSIS package with powershell on the server in asp.net. Please note i need to specify config file path also.

```
var processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
                {
                    Arguments = "dtexec /F " + "\"" + pkgPath + packageName +"\"",
                    FileName = "C:\\Windows\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe"
                };

                Process process = Process.Start(processStartInfo);
```

How to specify the config file path in the above code.

Comment: See [Running SSIS package programmatically](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/michen/archive/2007/03/22/running-ssis-package-programmatically.aspx), in particular option 3 - using SMO to execute a SQL Agent job. I don't know what the current thinking is about spawning arbitrary external processes directly from within ASP.NET - feels like a security risk to me.

Comment: Skip DTEXEC and just use the [SSIS API](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14738123/how-do-i-pass-dtexec-utility-command-line-arguments-to-process-start-using-c-sha/14738722#14738722)